# sed: substitute text with a string that contains special characters

Tags: text-processing, sed

I have a lot of text file with specific tag called "Comment", **example** I have a file called 3dchess.sh,

I need change the tag:

```
Comment=3D chess for X11
```

to

```
Comment='<span size="xx-large">3D chess for X11</b>'
```

The script is:

```
#!/bin/sh
Package=3dchess
Popcon=48
Section=universe

Comment=3D chess for X11
Exec=3Dc
```

I have tried this but it doesn't work in my case:

```
sed -i ':Comment=:s:Comment=:Comment='<span size="xx-large">:g;/Comment=/s/$/</b>'/' $HOME/3dchess.sh
```

Comment: The problem found for me is: the single quote in Comment=' and </b>' fail also the / between < >, how to solve it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Personally, I like the `-r` option of `sed` that allows extended regular expressions so parentheses don't need to be escaped:

```
sed -r "s#(Comment=)(.*)#\1'<span size=\"xx-large\">\2</b>'#" 3dchess.sh
```

Note that since you want to use `'` in the substitution, you cannot use `sed 's///'` but need to use `sed "s///"` instead. Also, since you need to have `/` as part of the pattern, you can't use that as a delimiter so you need to choose another character. I picked `#` but you can use anything you like. As Graeme said, once you're sure this works OK, add the `-i` switch to make it edit the file in place.

Answer (score 4):

```
sed 's:^Comment=\(.*$\):Comment='\''<span size="xx-large">\1</b>'\': \
  $HOME/3dchess.sh
```

Add `-i` when you are sure you have what you want.

#### Breakdown:

`s:x:y:` - This is the overall replacement pattern, basically replace `x` with `y`. Obviously we have a lot more between the colons above! Usually `:` is `/` but `sed` takes whatever comes after the `s` and using `/` here would mean you need to escape it in the pattern.

`^Comment=` - regex match `Comment=` at the start of a line ( `^` ). Good practice since it is possible (though unlikely) to get this elsewhere, which would cause problems.

`\(.*$\)` - match anything ( `.*` ) up to the end of the line ( `$` ). Surrounding with `\( \)` creates a back reference for use later.

`'\''` - close the `''` quotes, put a literal `'` and reopen quotes. Alternative method to @terdon's.

`Comment=<span size="xx-large">\1</b>` - replacement string, `\1` is the backreference from before.

`'\':` - close quotes, put a literal `'` then the final colon.

Comment: Hi, thanks; this works only half because doesn't write the single quote Comment=' and the final </b>'   :(

Comment: @davidva, oops missed that. Updated.

Comment: thanks, but the output is: 'Comment=3D chess for X11' , then this single quote enclose all tag, don't work

Comment: @davidva Really? I tested this and it works for me - `echo 'Comment=3D chess for X11' | sed 's:^Comment=\(.*$\):'\''Comment=<span size="xx-large">\1</b>'\':`. What shell are you using?

Comment: xfce4-terminal, but your line helpme with other tag where I needed convert: Icon=0ad to Icon=/usr/share/program/icons/0ad.png. Here: sed 's:^Icon=\(.*$\):\''Icon=/usr/share/program/icons/\1.png'\: $HOME/0ad.sh

Comment: @davidva, `xfce-terminal` is not a shell - http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/4126/what-is-the-exact-difference-between-a-terminal-a-shell-a-tty-and-a-con. Copy and paste the highlighted part above, it should work.

Comment: Shell text:bash; Shell graphic:XFCE; Linux Fedora

Comment: @davidva How about `bash --version`? This shouldn't affect it though, the example will surely work on any bash version. Are you *sure* everything has been copied correctly?

Comment: GNU bash, versión 4.2.45(1)-release (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu)

Comment: Exactly the same as me! You can do `sed --version` ( mine is `sed (GNU sed) 4.2.2`), but again this should work with all but really old versions. I can't see any other way this won't work apart from a copy error.

Comment: http://i61.tinypic.com/9ljqya.png  also sed (GNU sed) 4.2.2

Comment: @davidva Ok, I see, so the output isn't `'Comment=3D chess for X11'` (I thought the html tag was missing). I have moved the `'` quote. Hopefully it works as expected now.